# Select Combobox values in PHP with MySql Result

Tags: php, mysql

I am looking for some method to select a php combobox "<select>" based on results from mysql.

Actually I am working on a php form that will be used to edit existing values in mysql table. My first form will simply pass the id of the record to be edited, and this goes something like this <a href="editCalendar.php?id=15">Click to edit</a>

Code on editCalendar.php is as follows:

```
<?php
    include("dbpath.php");
    $id =  htmlspecialchars($_GET["id"]);

    $sql="Select * from event_Date where eventid=" . $id;
    $result=mysql_query($sql);

    // Check result
    // This shows the actual query sent to MySQL, and the error. Useful for debugging.
    if (!$result) 
    {
        $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
        $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
        die($message);
    }

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
    $name=$row["EventTitle"];
    $close=$row["OpenOrClose"];
    $remarks=$row["Remarks"];
    $date=$row["EventDate"];
    $type=$row["Type"];
    }
?>
```

The value obtained in `$close` will be used to select "SelectClosedOrOpen" on the same form, i.e. the user will get pre selected option from the populated list.

```
<select id="SelectClosedOrOpen">
<option value="3">Select</option>
<option value="0">Open</option>
<option value="1">Closed</option>
</select>
```

Means, if `$close` has 0, then `<option value="0">Open</option>` must be selected else if $close has 1 then `<option value="1">Closed</option>` should be automatically selected on formload.

Comment: Please stop using the deprecated [mysql extension](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). Switch to [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). Also be aware that your code is vulnerable to [SQL injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll just need to write the `selected` attribute in there.  Try this

```
<select id="SelectClosedOrOpen">
<option value="3" <?php echo ($close == 3) ? 'selected="selected"': ''; ?>>Select</option>
<option value="0" <?php echo ($close == 0) ? 'selected="selected"': ''; ?>>Open</option>
<option value="1" <?php echo ($close == 1) ? 'selected="selected"': ''; ?>>Closed</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I created this function some years back. I hope it helps you.
It basically requires an array of your options and the value of the option to be pre-selected. It returns the OPTIONS for your select, so you still have to create the SELECT tags, which allows you to customise the ID, JS etc..

```
function drop_down_box_options_from_array($choices,$default="") 
{
        $output= '';
        // $choices is contructed using $choices[]=array("value","Displayed Choice");
        while (list ($key, $val) = each ($choices))
        { 
                $output.= '<option value="';
                $output.= $choices[$key][0];
                if ($default==$choices[$key][0])
                {
                        $output.= '" selected="selected" >';
                }
                else
                {
                        $output.= '">';
                }
                $output.= $choices[$key][1];
                $output.= '</option>';
                $output.= "\n";
        }
        return $output;
}
```

Using your scenario:

```
<select id="SelectClosedOrOpen" name="OpenOrClose">
<?php
// defined here for clarity, but can be defined earlier ie in a config file
$choices[]=array('3', 'Select');
$choices[]=array('0', 'Open');
$choices[]=array('1', 'Closed');
echo drop_down_box_options_from_array($choices, $row['OpenOrClose']);
?>
</select>
```